# When will 4.4 LTS end, and what will replace it?

Tags: lts

Official support for CiviCRM version 4.4 as a [Long Term Support (LTS)](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35/what-is-the-civicrm-lts-version-and-should-i-use-it-or-the-latest-stable-releas) version began in the fall of 2014. When will it continue to, and which version will become the next LTS?

Comment: It might be helpful here to explain something about the rationale behind Long Term Support and how that can be of benefit to users, and/or link to somewhere else where that is explained.

Comment: This has been [pretty unclear](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34011.0) in the past. As I understand, LTS releases are community maintained and their releases have not been set in stone in the past and this makes it difficult to choose to use one. But this might help: "The 4.4 LTS will run for at least a year" Eileen, 22 Sep 2014 ([source](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,34011.msg145256.html#msg145256))

Comment: As you may have noticed I edited the question to link it to a question explaining what the LTS is. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

4.6 will be the next LTS version. The switch from 4.4 to 4.6 will probably occur at the end of 2015, since the 4.6 branch will be quite stable by then.

Comment: It would be helpful to point to a source for this information.

Comment: This is from internal discussions on the LTS discussion list of which I am a member. I'm not sure how to access our archives.

Comment: Perhaps a way forward in terms of clarity and transparency on LTS would be a forum board dedicated to it.

Comment: The LTS discussion list is archived on c.o like for the security and partners lists. Both of the latter should have archives only open to members, but LTS should be open to world in principle. There are likely other lists that I'm just not on that have open archives on c.o. If you think it's worthwhile maybe put in a JIRA issue on this to Andrew or Eileen.